# TYPO3 10.4: tx_news content elements rendering error

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x, tx-news

I am updating TYPO3 from Version 8 to 9 and 10. Now there is one error, I am not able to find a solution.

In tx_news details view I am using custom fluid templates. In TYPO3 8 and 9 everything works fine. In TYPO3 10.4 I get an error when showing the detail page:

> (1/1) #1381512761 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Type\Exception\InvalidEnumerationValueException
> Invalid value "FILE" for enumeration "TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\TableColumnSubType"

If I remove this code for content elements in the fluid template, the page will be shown without errors:

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.contentElements}">
    <!-- content elements -->
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering">{newsItem.contentElementIdList}</f:cObject>
</f:if>
```

As I'm using content elements, I need this code.

You can see the error at the moment here:
https://asienhaus104.der-koenig.net/aktuelles/detail/spenden-fuer-die-suedostasien

I tried lots of variants to solve this, but still the error will be there when I insert the fluid output for content elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a content element inside which is rendered in TypoScript with the FILE object (which was removed in v10). Take a look in your TypoScript (TypoScript object browser is best for this) and search for FILE objects (and replace them).

Here you can find the deprecation notice and a migration suggestion: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Deprecation-85970-FileContentObject.html

Comment: Hello Thomas, 

thanks a lot for your answer, I checked in TypoScript object browser für FILE objects. Indeed I was using the depracated template = FILE for marker based templates together with the extension "Modern Template Building - A historic TYPO3 piece". This worked so far.

Comment: To avoid any errors I changed to fluid templating page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE and altered the template. Now you see the fluid template in the frontend. 

I also removed the altered templates in tx_news. Now I am using the original tx_news templates in the EXT... folder. Still the same. I get the error when the contentelements are loaded. When I remove the contentelements code it works.

I did not find any other FILE object in TypoScript object browser.

Is there any other possibility to find this FILE object?

Comment: The same error appears? Or another one?

Comment: as the TSOB always is a projection, it might include some irrelevant typoscript. You can see the full typoscript in the "Template Analyzer".

Comment: Yeah, I solved it! You both brought me on the right track Thomas and @bernd-wilke-πφ. I look now into the Template Analyzer" and found the long-time out-dated extension "Media Content Elements" (mediace) still active...I deactivated mediace and the error is gone. (Amazing that mediace did not throw errors in Typo3 V8 oder V9)

Comment: As FILE was removed with v10 there could be no errors in v9, but you can look into deprecation log.